# Why comma separated iterables in for doesn't work like zip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

What I want to understand is why does the following code

```
for x, y in [1,2], [3,4]:
    print(x, y, x + y)
```

prints

```
1 2 3
3 4 7
```

instead of

```
1 3 4
2 4 6
```

Now, I know zip does this work and [not using zip to iterate over a pair of lists could be considered an anti-pattern](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/readability/not_using_zip_to_iterate_over_a_pair_of_lists.html), but I still need an explanation for this default behavior.

From my point of view, the code above should intuitively work just like the builtin zip function

```
for (x, y) in zip([1,2], [3,4]):
    print(x, y, x + y)
```

which prints

```
1 3 4
2 4 6
```

From memory I remember seeing the explanation for this technique a long time ago (and I guess that's why this solution comes to mind first), but I've done searches now, including on the whole section 5 of Python 3 documentation but I couldn't find any explanations for this behavior, not even on [section 5.6. (Looping Techniques)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques).

Is this a 4th [Gotcha](https://opensource.com/article/18/3/loop-better-deeper-look-iteration-python)?

Comment: `zip` would be pointless if they were the same.

Comment: The expression `[1,2], [3,4]` is a *tuple literal*, which results in a `tuple` with two elements, each of which is a list with two integers.

Comment: @schwobaseggl not if zip worked were this syntax wouldn't, as in list comprehensions for example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is the expected behavior!
Consider that `[1,2], [3,4]` is a tuple literal, equivalent to the tuple `([1,2], [3,4])`. (You might be using this without even noticing, for instance when assigning multiple values with `a, b, c = 10, 20, 30` disregarding the `()`...).

So in your example, the loop iterates through this list as follows:

```
# First iteration we get:
x, y = [1, 2]  
# Which is the same as:
x = 1
y = 2
# Which would print:
print(x, y, x+y)
>> 1, 2, 3

# Second iteration we get:
x, y = [3, 4]  
# Which is the same as:
x = 3
y = 4
# Which would print:
print(x, y, x+y)
>> 3, 4, 7
```

Does that make more sense now?

---

Considering zip: If zip would do the same thing, *then* I'd be suspicious! How is there this very common and considered-useful but completely redundant thing lying around? Hasn't anyone *noticed*? So you *shouldn't* expect them to do the same! ;-)

---

Edit due to a request for a pointer to documentation.
From [5.3 Tuples and Sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

> A tuple consists of a number of values separated by commas, for
>   instance: ...
>   As you see, on output tuples are always enclosed in
>   parentheses, so that nested tuples are interpreted correctly; they may
>   be input with or without surrounding parentheses, although often
>   parentheses are necessary anyway (if the tuple is part of a larger
>   expression).

Comment: It does make sense, I must say. But I find it odd that it is the tuple packing we're talking about. It's odd how it goes unnoticed that that's what's happening behind, because when you try to use that syntax in list comprehensions, python gives us back a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" in STDERR.

Comment: Also, is there any link from the docs which says that the expected behavior in this case is the tuple unpacking?

Comment: Can you give an example for such a fail-case? I added a link regarding parentheses-less defined tuples, which is all this is really about...

Comment: `l = [x + y for x, y in a, b]` doesn't run while `l = [x + y for x, y in (a, b)]` runs with no problems

Comment: That makes complete sense, due to ambiguity. Let's mark `x + y for x, y in a` as `ambiguous`, then you realize that a valid interpretation would be that `l` is a list `[ambiguous, b]`? not using parentheses only works in unambiguous situations. 
(On a more general note - if my answer helped, please accept or something [as one should on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).

Comment: I agree the ambiguity treatment makes sense. But I disagree that what you said would be a valid interpretation. Wouldn't `ambigous` be a generator object then, and an invalid one in this case? Also, `l = [x + y for x, y in a, b]` isn't "part of a larger expression". I was hoping for a more technical answer based on the docs, but it seems this can't be satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```
>>> [1,2],[3,4]
([1, 2], [3, 4])
>>> list(zip([1,2],[3,4]))
[(1, 3), (2, 4)]
>>>
```

The results are different, so when you iterate like:

```
for x,y in [1,2],[3,4]:
    ...
```

it's gonna be like:

```
x=1
y=2
# next loop
x=3
y=4
```

And when the loop is:

```
for x,y in zip([1,2],[3,4]):
    ...
```

It's iterating like:

```
x=1
y=3
# next loop
x=2
y=4
```

That's why Python created a `zip` method.

Comment: Is there any link from the docs which says that the expected behavior in this case is the tuple unpacking? Also, it would be nice if you could provide some link which tells us about the creation of the zip function in python.

Comment: @Mrioddo https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip for `zip` method on docs, but no explanation on the expected behavior

Answer (score 0):

An intuitive way to understand the first behaviour is to think about

```
for x, y in [1,2], [3,4]:
```

as a decomposition of

```
for z in [[1,2],[3,4]]:
```

where

```
z[0] = [1,2]
z[1] = [3,4]
```

Comment: I understand this is more intuitive for people who doesn't know/understand tuples very much, but to me it looks like the tuple unpacking is more accurately what really happens, don't you agree?